# How to access Raspberrypi Picamera from Google colaboratory

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, google-colaboratory, picamera, gradio

I was developing a plant disease detection system and finished training the dataset on model in the google collaboratory, now i want to use the picamera in the raspberry pi to show a leaf of the plant and detect the diseases.

I used Gradio in the Google collaboratory to create a web interface, then used the 'Image' Component as input, setting the source as 'webcam'. but the web application is not detecting the picamera. I am running all this in the Raspberry pi 4 model B, Raspberry pi OS bullseye.
I want to access the Picamera from the web

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question may yield more help over at [Raspberry PI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange where folks can speak to both the programming and the physical set up to help troubleshoot further